# Replace versionName with my own in AndroidManifest.xml using GithubActions in Xamarin solution

Tags: powershell, xamarin, migration, teamcity, github-actions

We are migrating from TeamCity to Github Actions. My goal is to replace versionName and versionCode with my custom parameters. This it a part of TeamCity PowerShell script:

```
$changeVersionName = 'android:versionName="' +$buildNumber +'"';
$changeVersionCode = 'android:versionCode="' +$ApkNumber +'"';

(Get-Content .\MobileAccess\MobileAccess.Droid\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml) `
-replace 'android:versionName="\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+"', $changeVersionName `
    -replace 'android:versionCode="\d+"', $changeVersionCode |
  Out-File .\MobileAccess\MobileAccess.Droid\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml -Encoding UTF8
```

So I have tried to execute `echo "::set-output name=manifestcontent::(Get-Content .\MobileAccess\MobileAccess.Droid\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml)"` in .sh file in order to receive the content of `AndroidManifest` to `main.yml` workflow in order to make an artifact with this content and replace with my own versions. Currently the problem is that I haven`t even get the content of `AndroidManifest`. Seems to me it can not find this file at all.

Actual questions:
1. Was this flow correct for this task? If no, what should I have to do?
2. What was a mistake in .sh when I tried to find `AndroidManifest` file and read it?

Comment: There's information missing. Please post a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your workflow yaml, the powershell script and the error message.